# Disable ability to deselect an item

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Is there a way to disable the ability to delect an item in ListView?
I have a SplitPage and when I deselect the selected item in ListView on the left the content on the right disappears because of lost databindings. I do not want that. I tried setting the ListView selectedItem back to the last one selected but the the back button in snap mode does not work

Comment: You can change the Enabled property to false which will prevent changing anything in the ListView.

Comment: thats not what I want. I want the lisView to behave as usual: user scrolls items, clicks on some and content is shown on the right. I just need to disable the ability to have no item selected (space or right click on selected item)

Comment: I had a similar problem [ListView Selection Double Tap Selecting the whole ListView Window Why?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winappswithcsharp/thread/827cc362-583f-4a95-9534-4e20ff569b2a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the selection mode to none and set your ItemTemplate to a restyled ToggleButton. Then you can bind the Enabled property of each button to the item view model and control the enabledness of each of them buttons separately.